# Getting error when I try to run a docker image on aws fargate windows 2019 full created on Windows 10 20h2

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, windows-container

I have Windows Docker Desktop, my os is Windows 10 enterprise , version 20h2

Docker for windows working... i have a small mvc asp.net3.1 application.

I create my docker image and i am able to run the container locally.

Everything is working from my local.
Now i uploaded the image to AWS ECR, create my taskDef and service.

Unfortunatelly the task does not start with the error :
*failed to create new container runtime task: failed to create shim: hcs::CreateComputeSystem 95cade147ae4418ab3d68ea1a2c70800-2341308736: The container operating system does not match the host operat*
I have seen some compatibility list from microsoft on the OS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11-21H2

I check i have hyperv and all..

Does anyone know how i can make the image compatible? This seems to be a known issues, but i am kind of blocked here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you have a different image version versus the host version. What is the base image on your dockerfile? And do you know what is the host version on your AWS environment? For reference, here's the documentation on host compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-2022%2Cwindows-11-21H2